# java script restrict alphabet in textbox not working on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i made a textbox in which i want to enter pincode 
of city and for that i want to allow enter only number for it. for this i used javascript function which is work well on pc but not working on mobile browser.
this website specially for mobile here is my code...

```
<script language="javascript"> 

  function mask(textbox, e) {                                 
      var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
      if (charCode == 46 || charCode > 31&& (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) 
     {
        alert("Only Numbers Allowed");
        return false;
     }
     else
     {
         return true;
     }
   }
</script>
```

HTML...

```
<input type="text"  id="p_len" value="" onkeypress="return mask(this,event);" maxlength="6" name="pincode" placeholder="Enter pincode"  ></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Check whether the function is getting called or not.Then Check keyCodes are same or not.

```
$(function () {
  $(document).keyup(function (e) {
     alert(e.keyCode);
  });
});
```